# How to use regexp to parse answer to question from text

Tags: sql, regex, netezza

I'm trying to parse text from data that looks like:

```
id      note_text 
--------------------------------------------------------------- 
1       Screening complete: YesÂCounseled 
2       A is 12 year oldÂÂ·Â°Â·Â°Screening complete: NO - multiple people presentÂ·Â°  
3       Â°calorie foods/snacksÂScreening complete: NO - card not availÂ·Â°Â·Â°
```

I simply have to figure out what phrase is following "Screening complete:", which are 3 answer options in set structure of following:

```
Yes 
NO - multiple people present 
NO - card not avail
```

As you can see, 'Screening Complete: [answer] ' is mixed in `note_text` column, surrounded by other texts that has no structure.

For an output, ideally, I'd like a separate text column created that shows:

```
id      note_text 
--------------------------------------------------------------- 
1       Screening complete: Yes
2       Screening complete: NO - multiple people present  
3       Screening complete: NO - card not avail
```

I've never worked with `regexp` expression, so I'm just completely lost on how to even approach to parse these certain phrases from free-text column. If someone can help guide me on how to write a regexp expression to extract what answer phrase comes after 'Screening complete:', that would be GREATLY appreciated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Netezza, you can use `regexp_replace()`:

```
select regexp_replace(note_text, '^.*(Screening complete:[^Â]+).*$', '\1')
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=797b86b8d39345caf68cc4a5f3792d3b) is a db<>fiddle using Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

The regex you are looking for is:

```
Screening complete: (?:(?!Â).)*
```

Find string "Screening complete: " and get everithing until find Â but not include Â

```js
const text = "Screening complete: YesÂCounseled \nA is 12 year oldÂÂ·Â°Â·Â°Screening complete: NO - multiple people presentÂ·Â°  \nÂ°calorie foods/snacksÂScreening complete: NO - card not availÂ·Â°Â·Â°";

console.log("Complete text");
console.log(text);
const matches = text.match(/Screening complete: (?:(?!Â).)*/g);

matches.forEach((item, index) => console.log(index + " match: ", item));
```